# error: [Errno 111] Connection refused in flask -mail

Tags: python, flask, flask-mail

I have two demos, the first does not work, but the second works. I want to understand why.

Error:

```
raise err
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

**__init__.py**

```
mail = Mail()

MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com'
MAIL_PORT = 465
MAIL_USE_TLS = False
MAIL_USE_SSL= True
MAIL_USERNAME = os.environ.get('MAIL_USERNAME')
MAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('MAIL_PASSWORD')

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])

    mail.init_app(app)
    app.debug = True

    return app

app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')
```

**views.py**

```
from ..mymail import mmail

mmail();
```

**mymail.py**

```
from flask.ext.mail import Message
from . import mail

def mmail():
    msg = Message(
      'Hello',
       sender='user@gmail.com',
       recipients=
       ['xxxxxxxxxx@hotmail.com'])
    msg.body = "This is the email body"
    mail.send(msg)
    return "Sent"
```

---

What is strange, this example will work correctly:

```
from flask.ext.mail import Mail, Message
import os

DEBUG = True

MAIL_SERVER='smtp.gmail.com'
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USE_TLS = False
MAIL_USE_SSL= True
MAIL_USERNAME = os.environ.get('MAIL_USERNAME')
MAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('MAIL_PASSWORD')

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(__name__)
    mail = Mail(app)

    msg = Message(
      'Hello',
       sender='user@gmail.com',
       recipients=
       ['xxxxxxxxxx@hotmail.com'])
    msg.body = "This is the email body"
    mail.send(msg)
    return "Sent"

app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')
```

So, what is the problem?

Comment: Where does `config` come from in the first example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that you are not comparing apples to apples.

- In the non-working example you configure your application with values from an unspecified dictionary-like object named `config` passing in the key found in the environment variable named `FLASK_CONFIG` (falling back to "default" if `FLASK_CONFIG` is not defined).

  ```
  app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
  ```
- In the *working* example you configure your application from the uppercase names defined in the current module:

  ```
  app.config.from_object(__name__)
  # config_name is ignored
  ```

Whatever key is being passed into the *non-working* example is providing an object which does not have the credentials which you want to use for `Mail`.

You can either:

- Configure your application via your defaults first and then load overrides from your `config` dictionary:

  ```
  app.config.from_object(__name__)
  app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
  ```
- Or ensure that your config has the correct values:

  ```
  config = {
      "development": SomeDevConfig,
      "staging": SomeStagingConfig,
      "production": SomeProductionConfig,
      "default": SomeDefaultConfig
  }
  ```